# using ROW_NUMBER() for 2 columns

Tags: sql-server

Please need help to solve this issue
I have a table Meeting

```
PersonOne   PersonTwo
Ajay        Bharat
Ajay        Elas
Chetan      Deepak
Deepak      Chetan
Chetan      Deepak
Farooq      Ajay
Anil        Sanjay
Gaganan     Hassan
Hassan      Isqh
```

Output should be

```
PersonOne   PersonTwo    
Anil        Sanjay
```

If user wants to show only persons  who have attended meeting only once
here Bharat as attanded meeting only once but he had attended meeting with ajay, who had attended the meeting more then once. so Bharat should not show in the list

Output should be

```
PersonOne   PersonTwo    
Chetan      Deepak
Deepak      Chetan
Chetan      Deepak
```

If user wants to show only persons  who have attended meeting for third time
I have tried almost all possible statements , like ,`ROW_NUMBER() ,RANK() ,DENSE_RANK()  ,NTILE` but result..plz need your help

Comment: More information would be good. I assume there's more than one person in the Meeting table? In that case we'd need to know how many person columns there are. And if possible, it might be a good idea to normalize the tables and make a separate Meeting table for the individual meetings, and then add the participants to a "Participant" table which references Meeting. Also, would be good to see what you've done so far to get a better picture of the question.

Comment: I've updated my previous answer. It also have working Fiddle link. Please check it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

The query below will take some time - no doubt, but definitely it will give you expected result.

```
SELECT * FROM tblMeeting WHERE (PersonOne IN
(
    SELECT PersonOne FROM 
    (
        SELECT PersonOne, COUNT(*) AS Expr1 FROM 
        (
            SELECT PersonOne FROM tblMeeting AS tblMeeting_3
            UNION ALL
            SELECT PersonTwo FROM tblMeeting AS tblMeeting_1
        ) AS derivedtbl_1 GROUP BY PersonOne
    ) AS derivedtbl_2 WHERE (Expr1 = 1)

)) 
AND (PersonTwo IN 
(
    SELECT PersonOne FROM 
    (
        SELECT PersonOne, COUNT(*) AS Expr1 FROM
        (
            SELECT PersonOne FROM tblMeeting AS tblMeeting_2
            UNION ALL
            SELECT PersonTwo FROM tblMeeting AS tblMeeting_1
        ) AS derivedtbl_1_1 GROUP BY PersonOne
    ) AS derivedtbl_2_1 WHERE (Expr1 = 1)
))
```

Here is Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51b91/4

P.S : You can improve the query performance. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below query

```
SELECT Person
INTO #TEMP
FROM
(
   SELECT PersonOne as Person FROM tblMeeting
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT PersonTwo  as Person FROM tblMeeting
) P
GROUP By Person 
Having Count(Person) =1

select * from tblMeeting where 
PersonOne in ( select Person from #TEMP) and
PersonTwo in ( select Person from #TEMP)
```